# Vuetify sparkline throws error. How to resolve?

Tags: vuetify.js

Vuetify sparkline is throwing this error if I add auto-draw to it.

```
          <v-sparkline
            :value="createdUserDates.values"
            :line-width="2"
            stroke-linecap="round"
            auto-draw
            smooth
            :height="50"
          >
          </v-sparkline>
```

This is the error:

> [Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTotalLength' of undefined"

the value of createdUserDates.values:

> [2, 3, 5, 6]

Comment: I figured this out on my own. It happens when there are no values in the value array on initial render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens when there are no values in the value array on initial render.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get rid of the errors by setting auto-draw to be true only when the values length is truthy:

```
<v-sparkline
  :labels="todayLabels"
  :value="todayValues"
  :auto-draw="!!todayValues.length"
></v-sparkline>
```